# how to make the password not required FOS Bundle

Tags: symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

On my Symfony2 project, How to make a password non-mandatory (is not mandatory but mandatory on adding a new profile) when updating the user's profile using FOS User Bundle from Symfony2

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override profile form and define only the fields you need.

Update config to use new form type:

```
# app/config.yml
fos_user:
    #... other options
    profile:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
```

I am not 100% sure, I you might need to define your new form type as service:

```
# app/services.yml or other config file you define services in
services:
    AppBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType:
        arguments:
            - '%fos_user.model.user.class%'
```

Define fields in you own form type:

```
// AppBundle/Form/Type/ProfileFormType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as FosProfileFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends FosProfileFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'firstname',
                null,
                [
                    'label' => 'form.label_firstname',
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'lastname',
                null,
                [
                    'label' => 'form.label_lastname',
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'password',
                PasswordType::class,
                [
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

Of course non-required password is most likely not what you want, possible you don't want to show to field in form at all, so just remove it.